# Is using a passive RC high pass filter at the output of an opamp a good method to remove DC offset?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, high-pass-filter, dc-offset

All the information I am able to find related to this discuss about AC coupling the inputs of an amplifier but never the output. I wish to know if there are any issues with AC coupling at the output. It seems like a fairly obvious solution to me for remove DC offsets from AC signal, I am surprised to see that this is not common. Is there something I am missing here?

For clarification, I mean something like this:

[image]

Comment: Generally we do use AC couple to connect to next stage and that blocks DC. But while adding adding a capacitor , one thing we should note is that we are driving some load with capacitance CL and that will attenuate some part of the signal

Comment: The series capacitance provides a DC bias that allows a DC bias shift in order to remove the DC bias. But a capacitor is a frequency-variable resistor, so to speak. So you do need to keep in mind it's relative impedance. Also, it is a differentiator, so there's a phase shift. And it **is** fairly common. How did you come to the idea that it isn't so commonly used? It doesn't have to be used, perhaps more so in cases using bipolar supplies. But do you have specific cases to show to help us see what you are seeing?

Comment: @jonk Most articles only describe AC coupling the inputs, such as this (https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/common-problems-when-designing-amplifier-circuits.html), never seen any discussion about output.

Comment: @needbrainscratched Oh... were we discussing outputs? I thought just intermediate connections between stages. My mistake!

Answer (score 2):

It's a method that works in some cases. Is it good? It depends.

You have shown an op-amp with a DC gain of 10. The amplifier output will be 10x the input DC offset. If that is small enough to continue to operate without hitting the rails, then no input AC coupling is OK. Often however, we might have a large input offset, or configure the opamp for a larger stage gain, and it may be necessary to input AC couple the signal to keep the opamp within its operating region.

The load may require a low impedance drive at all frequencies, even DC. Then an output capacitor cannot be used.

If neither of those apply, then it's good. The most common application of output AC coupling I've seen is for a single-rail audio amplifier to be connected to a loudspeaker referenced to the negative rail, with an electrolytic capacitor generally in the high 100s or low thousands of uF. But that connection is to remove the mid-rail output operating bias of the amplifier, its input is invariably AC coupled as well.

Answer (score 1):

Its more common on inputs, if you only want to remove offset because: inputs usually have very high impedance and you dont amplify the offset granting larger signal range.

But it does work at outputs. It is routinely used when driving e.g. small speakers from single supplies.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it will work (quite well).